# can IIS smtp role in windows server 2016 send mails direct to internet without exchange server or smart host?

Tags: iis

I have a Web based application, through which I intend to send email notifications to the users . I have put a IIS SMTP role on Windows 2016 Standard edition .
Do I need anything else apart from the SMTP server, like the Exchange server for sending Emails. Again for clarification I only need to send Emails to the users and I am not suppose to receive emails through it

can IIS smtp role in windows server 2016 send mails directly to the internet without an exchange server or smart host?

Comment: For most IIS SMTP articles from Microsoft, a note has been added to claim the deprecation of that component, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above#note So no matter what you read from elsewhere, you cannot use that role any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything that speaks proper SMTP “can” send email to the Internet. However, there’s a certain amount of knowledge you need to be reasonably sure that anyone actually receives the email you send.

The first hurdle: It’s not uncommon for ISPs to block SMTP traffic from their customers unless you have a subscription that explicitly allows your company to host your own mail servers. And if you’re a smaller company your IP address may be in a range that recipient mail servers  recognize as likely to be “residential” rather than commercial, meaning they may block your email outright or increase its spamminess score massively in their filters.

If that’s not an issue for you, you will need to configure at least [SPF](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework), but preferably also [DKIM](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DomainKeys_Identified_Mail) and [DMARC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMARC) records in your DNS, to make recipients able to confirm that your sender server is allowed to send email in the name of your domain.

It’s also good form to present a valid reverse DNS record for the sending server (talk to your ISP about that).

Finally you will in all likelihood be marked as suspicious unless your domain actually does have MX records and therefore some way to receive email.

Comment: As @MikaelH mentioned, DKIM is highly preferable but it's unfortunately not natively supported by Windows Server 2016, you can add [DKIM for IIS](https://www.interactivethoughts.com/products/thinkdkim/) by this 3rd party component though.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the IIS SMTP role on Windows 2016 is capable of direct delivery it is not necessarily a good idea, as Mikael H has explained in his answer.

If you send email from your domain, you have some kind of email infrastructure in place already, whether it is on-premises or in cloud. This infrastructure is already configured and tested to be able to deliver the mail, and likely has the SPF+DKIM+DMARC in place, too. Setting up a service account and using it as a smarthost would save you from a lot of work.

Comment: thanks Esa, we have exchange 2016 on-prem already with SPF+DKIM+DMARC in place  but once try send mail from iis smtp direct to internet it failed , once change the smtp setting in iis to exchange server is working fine , my goal is to know it's possible to use iis smtp without exchange server, the mail flow should go throw exchange !!